# VBA Set Workbook does not assign correctly when workbook is already open

Tags: vba, excel, loops, set

This might turn out to be a beginners question, I think I am missing something basic here.

The user selects different Excel-files, which names are stored in the String array `fileNames`. The macro is then meant to crawl through the selected files and translate a specific worksheet to XML.

```
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

'Select Leveling pattern files from the file system
Dim fileNames() As String
fileNames = ChooseLevelingPatternFiles()

'Create new .xml-file
Dim pathDelivList As String
pathDelivList = "X:\..\..\DeliveryList.xml"

Open pathDelivList For Output As #1
'Print XML header into new file
Print #1, "<?xml version=""1.0"" encoding=""ISO-8859-1"" standalone=""yes""?>"
Print #1, "<StramaDeliveryPlans>"

'Create new .xml-file 
Dim pathShiftInfo As String
pathShiftInfo = "X:\..\..\ShiftInformationFromLP.xml"

Open pathShiftInfo For Output As #2
'Print XML header into new file
Print #2, "<?xml version=""1.0"" encoding=""ISO-8859-1"" standalone=""yes""?>"
Print #2, "<ShiftInformationFromLevelingPlans>"

'Define Object for Target Workbook and Target Worksheet
Dim Target_Workbook As Workbook
Dim Target_Worksheet As Worksheet
Dim Target_Path as String, currentLPType() As String


'''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
' Enter loop through different files
'''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
Dim i As Integer
For i = 0 To UBound(fileNames) - 1

   'Change the path of the target file and assign the Leveling Pattern worksheet to the variable
   Target_Path = fileNames(i)

   Application.DisplayAlerts = False
   Set Target_Workbook = Nothing
   Set Target_Workbook = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=Target_Path, UpdateLinks:=xlUpdateLinksNever, ReadOnly:=True, Notify:=True)
   Set Target_Worksheet = Nothing
   Set Target_Worksheet = Target_Workbook.Sheets("Leveling Pattern")


   'Print title of current file
   currentLPType = Split(Target_Workbook.Name, " ")
   Print #1, "<" + currentLPType(0) + "_" + currentLPType(1) + ">"
   Print #2, "<" + currentLPType(0) + "_" + currentLPType(1) + ">"


   '''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
   ' A lot of code only affecting the current sheet
   '''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''


   'Before closing the file close the containing xml element
   Print #1, "</" + currentLPType(0) + "_" + currentLPType(1) + ">"
   Print #2, "</" + currentLPType(0) + "_" + currentLPType(1) + ">"

   'Target_Workbook.Close False

   Application.DisplayAlerts = False
   DoEvents

Next i

'''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
' Exit loop through different files
'''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''

' Close the .xml files
Print #1, "</StramaDeliveryPlans>"
Close #1
Print #2, "</ShiftInformationFromLevelingPlans>"
Close #2

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

**Problem:** 
`Set Target_Workbook = Workbooks.Open(Target_Path)` is not working properly. The Workbook object always holds to the first assignment made and processes every time the same file.

I tried `Target_Workbook = Nothing` before the assignment but no effect. `Target_Path = fileNames(i)` is working fine.

What am I doing wrong? Any help is appreciated.

**Edit2:** 
The problem seems only to be ocurring when the target workbook is already open, so the underlying problem seems to be that macro is unable to select an already opened file.

Comment: move the variable declarations (e,g, Dim Target_Workbook As Workbook) outside the loop.

Comment: This has no effect.

Comment: Is the `Target_Path` a full path + filename or just filename?

Comment: `Target_Path` looks like `X:\...\...\filename.xls`. `Target_Workbook.Name`looks like `filename.xls`.

Comment: For being sure about the array, add a `debug.print i & "--" & fileNames(i) & "--" & now` right behind the `Target_Path = fileNames(i)`. I entered your code in Ms Excel 2003 SP2, works like a charm.

Comment: Would have felt too dumb if that was the solution, so of course I tried this before. However, I found out that the **problem only exists if I do not close the treated workbook via `Target_Workbook.Close False` at the end of the current loop iteration**. Any idea why this could be the case? As the Excel-files I am working with are pretty big, they always take forever to open again, so I'd prefer to leave this out.

Comment: @cr44sh -- you can only declare a variable **once**.  A `Dim` statement inside a loop will declare the same variable repeatedly.

Comment: Do you have an `On Error Resume Next` that you haven't shown?

Comment: @ashleedawg I just shifted the variable-declaration to outside of the loop, but still encounter the same behaviour. The workbook does not get updated when it has not been closed at the end of the previous iteration.

Comment: @Rory no, nothing like that.

Comment: I think you need to post all the code then. There is no reason for what you describe based on what you have posted, although it's not clear why you aren't looping the full array.

Comment: @Rory I edited the posting. I hope you spot something :)

Comment: How are you determining that `Target_Workbook` is the problem rather than the later code (which is omitted but mentions "current sheet" which always makes me nervous)?

Comment: I put `Debug.print Target_Workbook.Name` after the assignment and it produces the same output every iteration. I'm wondering though why it is only happening when the workbook does not get closed before. Is the workbook-object maybe blocked towards new assignments as long as it has not been closed?

Comment: After code can't close the problem file, can you open it manually and close it?There may be something special about that file? Try `Workbook.Open(Filename:=Target_Path, UpdateLinks:=xlUpdateLinksNever, ReadOnly:=True, Notify:=True)`, Also add `DoEvents` at end of loop to prevent Excel not responding.

Comment: No difference @PatricK . I edited the posting and also found out that the problem only affects workbooks that have not been already opened before. So the macro seems to have problems to get his hands on an already opened file.

Comment: That's what I guessed, try disable Alerts before open, then enable it back afterwards. `Application.DisplayAlerts = False` that should remove the Notify prompt.

Comment: Not sure how this can help, but I edited the code as shown above. Yet no improvement. Thanks for your ongoing willingness to help by the way.